# How to know if a txt file is already open with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open/create a txt file with Excel VBA, but before opening the file I need to make sure it is not already open.

How can I know if it's open, and if so, close it before opening it again ?

Something like :

```
If IsOpen(File_Name) Then
    Close(File_Name)
EndIf
```

Comment: Just check if it's open

Comment: did you check out this? [LINK](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ISFILEOPEN.ASPX)

Comment: Thanks for the link Dubison, but his code didn't work for me.. Even if my txt file is already open, his code still stays it is not open

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to re-create the same file from scratch, if the file tests open, then why don't you just use it? If it tests NOT open, then open it. Then, if it doesn't exist create it.

You may just clear out the text file if it is open and you want to restart the text instead of overwriting by creating the file again.

Comment: Because I used the function `iFile = FreeFile` and `Open Txt_Path & File_Name For Output As iFile` to be able to write in the txt file, and I don't know how to write in it if it's already open... So i prefer to close it to re-open it this way ^^